# Wordpress curl sending default content type

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I am using a wordpress site. I want to hit an api via php curl request. I have written the code on local, it works fine. Then i uploaded the exact same code on live server. Its giving the http_code 404 page not found. Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "strJSON=" . json_encode($php_array));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
$cInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Here is the print_r of `$cInfo` on live site:

```
[url] => url
[content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
[http_code] => 404
[header_size] => 402
[request_size] => 556
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
```

Here is the print of `$cInfo` on local site:

```
[url] => url
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 519
[request_size] => 450
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
```

The site is based on wordpress. The difference is just of `content_type` and `httpcode`

Comment: You also have to account for mod_rewirte and .htaccess on your production environment.  Does URL point to an actual file?

Comment: Yes url point to actual file.

Comment: you can test curl ( on linux at least ) via command line to see if the file is reachable.

Comment: I think Api url is not an issue, because it is working fine on local.

Comment: You wouldn't get a 404 if that url was reachable... just because one is local and one is not, they are 2 different environments.   It's best to rule out the possibility that the url can be reached when you have a 404, the server wont lie to you.  So either the url is wrong, or something like mod_rewrite ( environment specific ) is blocking it.